# Assigning new variable to a list of arrays in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to assign a new variable `K` to a list of arrays `Path`. However, I don't know how to append a list of arrays. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np

Path=[np.array([10.                 ,  0.6382821834929432 ,  0.5928417218382795 ,
        0.5542698411479658 ,  0.6677634679746701 ,  0.8578897621707481 ,
        0.6544597670890333 ,  0.32706383813570833,  0.8966468940380192 ]),
np.array([10.                 ,  0.6262206291648664 ,  0.6413512609273813 ,
        0.5417310533794202 ,  0.763557281407787  ,  0.580075670670837  ,
        0.48048196888232686,  0.8537221497408958 ,  0.35651700423205657,
        0.9720842635477158 ])]

for i in range(0,2):
    K=Path[i]
    print([K])
```

The current output is

```
[array([10.                 ,  0.6382821834929432 ,  0.5928417218382795 ,
        0.5542698411479658 ,  0.6677634679746701 ,  0.8578897621707481 ,
        0.6544597670890333 ,  0.32706383813570833,  0.8966468940380192 ])]
[array([10.                 ,  0.6262206291648664 ,  0.6413512609273813 ,
        0.5417310533794202 ,  0.763557281407787  ,  0.580075670670837  ,
        0.48048196888232686,  0.8537221497408958 ,  0.35651700423205657,
        0.9720842635477158 ])]
```

The expected output is

```
[array([10.                 ,  0.6382821834929432 ,  0.5928417218382795 ,
        0.5542698411479658 ,  0.6677634679746701 ,  0.8578897621707481 ,
        0.6544597670890333 ,  0.32706383813570833,  0.8966468940380192 ]),
array([10.                 ,  0.6262206291648664 ,  0.6413512609273813 ,
        0.5417310533794202 ,  0.763557281407787  ,  0.580075670670837  ,
        0.48048196888232686,  0.8537221497408958 ,  0.35651700423205657,
        0.9720842635477158 ])]
```

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid expression in Python. The brackets don't match.

Comment: What do you mean by "new variable K".  Do you mean adding a new dimension to the shape of each array?

Comment: Isn't your expected output just what's in the Path variable already?

Comment: It's the same as ```Path``` but then I have simplified it here so that I can incorporate in a different code.

Comment: if you want to copy the list you can just do K = list(Path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is about copying!

The answer is [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
from copy import deepcopy
K = deepcopy(Path)
```

None of the following assignments works because changing items in `K`, changes items in `Path`:

```
K = Path
K = list(Path)
K = Path[:]
```

Because:

```
K[0][0] = np.random.rand()
print(K[0][0] == Path[0][0])
# True
```

If you make a deep copy of `Path` into `K`, changing items in `K` won't change `Path`.